# ReSharper's autocompletion bug?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

I'm trying to call a method with many parameters in vs2008. Resharper's (v5) intellisense shows only few of them and then "Use smart Completion to see all". OK, I'm pressinf Ctrl+Shift+Space - and after that he shows some stupid suggestions like "String.Concat, String.Copy...", but I want to see as usual what name and type of parameter I need to pass into the method.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: If you are still evaluating Resharper you might also want to have a look at VisualAssist, I found that it works better with unmanaged code than Resharper.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots or probably a video for a visual representation of your problem? Thanks

Answer (score 18):

I also get the same message "Use smart Completion to see all" when I should be seeing all the options.

My Resharper settings are a little bit flaky. I am using Visual Studio keyboard scheme with several Resharper overrides.

**If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> , when entering parameter values, it will show you all the options.**

Answer (score 2):

For me, the shortcut is `CTRL-P`.  If that doesn't work for you, go to Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard, and search for "ReSharper.ReSharper_ParameterInfo_Show" and give it whatever keybinding you like.

Incidentally, `CTRL-SHIFT-Space` is for "smart completion" which helps you discover local variables/fields/etc. that are applicable at the current context.  This is very useful when you have something like this:

```
string s = _
```

Where your cursor is at `_`.  Now, using smart completion, it will return a list that *only* contains string variables/fields/etc.

Comment: I tried Ctrl + P: intellisense window that is sending me to Smart completion just become transparent. Nothing else happens.

Comment: @pukipuki, did you check the keybinding like I suggested?